# sum of a single column

Tags: list, item

on the newform.aspx, there is a field to enter the number of students who were part of a training workshop. I need to dynamically add and show the total of hours so our management can see it at a glance.

Comment: Hi,  What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Oops! It is SP2010

Comment: newform.aspx is usually used to add a new item to a list.  So I am unsure why a manager would need to see total number of hours when adding a list item.  Sounds like you may need to generate another form that is more of a report that your managers can access to get the required information.  Could you explain the process a little more?  Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. In the view settings there is an option to display the column total and to display it by person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having a real answer to this question let me rephrase your last comment and add one answer here.

If you want to show a sum, count, average on the list view you should use list aggregations in the view settings as shown on the screenshot.

[image: View Settings]

If you want to achieve the same on the NewForm.aspx you will have to add a content editor webpart and execute some JS to sum up the value from the other items.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I originally posted this over a year ago, and soon after figured it out but thanks for the extra info.

Comment: Hey Jackie, if this qualifies as an answer for your question, please mark it as an answer too.